# How can I verify if my implementation about SSL Pining using Retrofit is all right?

Tags: java, android, security, ssl, mobile

I'm using the PEM certificate alocated in AWS on S3, my application is using TLS Mutual and other verifications, but now I must implement SSL Pining.
This is my implementation:
` public static OkHttpClient generateSecureOkHttpClient(Context context)  {

```
    OkHttpClient.Builder httpClientBuilder = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
    AssetManager assetManager = context.getAssets();
    try{
        InputStream caFileInputStream = assetManager.open(PFX_FILE);
        KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
        keyStore.load(caFileInputStream, PASS_CERT.toCharArray());
        KeyManagerFactory keyManagerFactory = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance("X509");
        keyManagerFactory.init(keyStore, PASS_CERT.toCharArray());
        SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
        sslContext.init(keyManagerFactory.getKeyManagers(),null, new SecureRandom());
        SSLSocketFactory sslSocketFactory = sslContext.getSocketFactory();
        String publicKeyFingerprint = getPublicKeyFingerprint(context);
        httpClientBuilder
                .sslSocketFactory(sslSocketFactory)
                .certificatePinner(getCertificatePinner(publicKeyFingerprint))
                .readTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .connectTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }catch (KeyStoreException | CertificateException | NoSuchAlgorithmException | IOException | KeyManagementException | UnrecoverableKeyException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return httpClientBuilder
            .build();
}

private static String getPublicKeyFingerprint(Context context) throws IOException {
    String output = null;
    try (InputStream caFileInputStream = context.getAssets().open(PATH_PEM_CERT)){
        int available = caFileInputStream.available();
        byte [] fileBytes = new byte[available];
        caFileInputStream.read(fileBytes);
        byte [] hashBytes = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256").digest(fileBytes);
        String hash = new BigInteger(1, hashBytes).toString(16);
        output = String.format("sha256/%s=", hash);
    }catch (IOException | NoSuchAlgorithmException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return output;
}

private static CertificatePinner getCertificatePinner(String publicKeyFingerprint){
    CertificatePinner output = null;
    CertificatePinner.Builder builder = new CertificatePinner.Builder();
    builder.add(URL_PROD_SSL, publicKeyFingerprint);
    output = builder.build();
    return output;
}`
```

Is My implementation correct? Is there other implementation that I could try?

I tried use Certificate PFX, the second test was using his .crt file and now I'm trying PEM certificate
How can I verify if my piner is ok?